# use if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two functions that increment the same variable.
One of each have own html button to run onClick.

```
function click1() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('click-count').innerHTML=clicks;
}
function click2() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('click-count').innerHTML=clicks;
}
```

and inside function click1() I have if statement which add new line of text when clicks=5

```
if (clicks==5) {
var log = document.createElement("p");
log.innerHTML = 'clicks 5';
document.getElementById('clicks-log').appendChild(log);
}
```

but when I made 5 clicks by click2() function the if statement are not work and if I put if statement outside any functions it didn't work at all. Is there any way to handle var clicks from all functions to make if statement work?

Comment: Write a *third* function that does the increment and the check, and call that function from both of the others.

Comment: Please post your full code (where is the IF statement from your second code block in the `click1()` function declaration from the first code block?).

Comment: It appears you want the two functions to be identical.  Why not bind all events to `click1`?

Comment: What's the point of 2 functions that do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're defining the on click attribute of the elemt, you could do:

```
<button onclick="click1();docheck();">first button</button>

<button onclick="click2();docheck();">second button</button>
```

And define the function:

```
function docheck() {
  if (clicks == 5) {
    var log = document.createElement("p");
    log.innerHTML = 'clicks 5';
    document.getElementById('clicks-log').appendChild(log);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, really helped alot to know how to handle things from different functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your if statement in both functions, or make the control in an other function you call from both click1 and click2 :

```
var clicks = 0;

function click1() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('click-count').innerHTML=clicks;
    checkClicksNumber();
}
function click2() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('click-count').innerHTML=clicks;
    checkClicksNumber();
}

function checkClicksNumber(){
    if (clicks==5) {
        var log = document.createElement("p");
        log.innerHTML = 'clicks 5';
        document.getElementById('clicks-log').appendChild(log);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 12 seconds!

Comment: Lol... I thought this comment was spam :P

Answer (score 1):

Clicks should be a global variable, lying outside all your functions.

```
var clicks = 0;

function click1() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('click-count').innerHTML=clicks;
}

function click2() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('click-count').innerHTML=clicks;
}

//Some function that uses 'clicks'
function readClicks(){
    if (clicks==5) {
        var log = document.createElement("p");
        log.innerHTML = 'clicks 5';
        document.getElementById('clicks-log').appendChild(log);
    }
}
```

Try this.